# Twilio Use Case

Tags: twilio

I am considering using Twillio as an extension in an existing application.
My use-case is this:

1. User clicks button in application
2. Using Twilio API, the application calls the user.
3. The user answers their phone
4. Twilio connects user to some phone number. (fetched from db)

It's a bit strange, but it is exactly my customer's request.  Before I spend too much time in the rabbit hole, I thought I would ask the community, can I do this with Twilio APIs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twilio developer here!

This is definitely a common use case for Twilio. In fact, it's so common that we wrote up an in-depth tutorial showing you how to build an app like the one you described.

We've got it in PHP, Node, Python, and Ruby - here's the PHP version:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/walkthrough/click-to-call/php/laravel

If you prefer to just reference the code, you can find it on GitHub too: https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/clicktocall-laravel

Comment: I'm working on this now.  I am finding it difficult to uncouple Twilio from this Laravel framework, while I'm in learning mode. Are there any resources which don't require the developer to reverse-engineer Laravel?

Comment: To call Twilio's Helper Library in PHP use the information on this page:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/php/install

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  That's actually very simple in Twilio:

```
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls
```